# How do I correctly update a Haskell records held in Data.IORef?

Tags: haskell

I have [this simple project](https://github.com/bigos/cairo-example/blob/4945d174df7ac1b1cf947f6eb9a38c9c45973dd2/src/Main.hs) where I tried to experiment with Haskell and Cairo library.

I ran into a problem with redrawing the state of the application. At the moment  I have the record that holds global state. I had to store it in `Data.IORef` monad in order to be able to pass the data from one GUI event to another.

I was inspired by Elm to try it like that, but I wonder if there is better way to do it?

I'm particularly concerned about this fragment in main function.

```
-- update globalModel in place
readIORef globalModel >>= (\m -> writeIORef globalModel (Model
                                                         (fromIntegral kv)
                                                         (if ((keyToHeading (fromIntegral kv)) == None)
                                                           then (heading m)
                                                           else (keyToHeading (fromIntegral kv)))))
```

Please advice of better approach.

Comment: `IORef` is not a monad.

Comment: it shows you I am a noob :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be a simpler refactoring. Note that [`modifyIORef'`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-IORef.html#v:modifyIORef-39-) combines `readIORef` and `writeIORef` into a single strict operation:

```
ifNoneThen :: Heading -> Heading -> Heading
None `ifNoneThen` x = x
h    `ifNoneThen` _ = h

updateModel :: Int -> Model -> Model
updateModel kv oldModel = Model newKv newHeading
    where newKv      = fromIntegral kv
          newHeading = keyToHeading newKv `ifNoneThen` heading oldModel

foo :: Int -> Model -> IO ()
foo kv globalModel = modifyIORef' globalModel (updateModel kv)
```

- A small utility function for `Header`s, `ifNoneThen` (that you might be able to use elsewhere as well) cleans up the `if` statement in the body of the code.
- Some minor refactoring to remove duplicated calls (why call `fromIntegral kv`  3 times if you can call it once and give the result a meaningful name?).
- Factoring the pure code (construction of the new model from an old model) out of the impure code (updating the `IORef`) makes it easier to reason about the code - there's fewer places for unexpected side-effects to crop up.

Comment: Why not factor out the model change from the `IORef` business? The latter is something like `modifyIORef'`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have learned new things about Haskell today.

Comment: Using modifyIORef' can lead to problems in some circumstances https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50320430/why-my-haskell-game-sometimes-responds-differently-to-the-same-arguments

Comment: @ruby_object This is a semantically equivalent refactoring of your original code (asides from being strict in the new model) - it didn't sound like multithreading was a consideration from your original question.